# Exporting image (png, jpeg) from Photoshop to Acrobat PDF - bad quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, adobe-acrobat

I have a portfolio design in Photoshop, and I when I save that as an image file format, it gets compressed and low quality if I try to import it in Acrobat.

I just want to export from PSD as an image and then import to Acrobat to create a PDF from that image(s).

Am I doing this wrong? Is there any other way to create a PDF from images?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply save as a PDF from Photoshop?

Comment: I could, but can I combine multiple PDFs into a single PDF?

Comment: If you have Acrobat, yes. Simply drag pages from one PDF to the Pages Pane in the other PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what Scott said. Also just to mention if you have Acrobat, arranging the multiple files in numerical order in a folder before combining them will ensure that your portfolio PDF shows up in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I would export to PDF as suggested, but for your information: when exporting an image to then place in acrobat as you describe (or any DTP software for print), this is one of those times where you need to consider DPI (or PPI).

When you make PDFs, the paradigm used is print publication, and (for typical commercial printing) one expects images that provide about 300 pixels per printed inch.

What this means is that if you want an image to be of suitable quality when printed, and you are going **to fill the page to the edges of an 8.5 x 11 inch sheet of paper** (without scaling or stretching), you want to **ensure that your image is 2550 pixels  x 3300 pixels**. Further, you want to choose a non-lossy compression and storage format such as TIFF. If you want to use Jpeg, go with something above around 85% quality as a minimum.

If you provide fewer pixels than 2550 x 3300 and still set the image to print at 8.5 x 11 inches, the image must be scaled up and scaling up enlarges artifacts.

It is important to understand that "setting the DPI" is just offering a suggestion to software. The only thing that matters is the number of pixels you provide.